# Why does the order of expressions matter in re.match?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-re

I'm making a function that will take a string like "three()" or something like "{1 + 2}" and put them into a list of token (EX: "three()" = ["three", "(", ")"]  I using the re.match to help separate the string.

```
def lex(s):
# scan input string and return a list of its tokens
seq = []
patterns = (r"^(\t|\n|\r| )*(([a-z])*|[0-9]|\(|\)|\*|\/|)(\t|\n|\r| )*")
m = re.match(patterns,s)
while m != None:
    if s == '':
        break
    seq.append(m.group(2))
    s = s[len(m.group(0)):]
    m = re.match(patterns,s)
return seq
```

This one works if the string is just "three". But if the string contains "()" or any symbol it stays in the while loop.
But a funny thing happens when move ([a-z])* in the pattern string it works. Why is that happening?

```
works: patterns = (r"^(\t|\n|\r| )*([0-9]|\(|\)|\*|\/|([a-z])*)(\t|\n|\r| )*")
Does not work: patterns = (r"^(\t|\n|\r| )*(([a-z])*|[0-9]|\(|\)|\*|\/)(\t|\n|\r| )*")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one is a bit tricky, but the problem is with this part `([a-z])*`. This matches any string of lowercase letters size *0* (zero) or more.

If you put this sequence at the end, like here:

```py
patterns = (r"^(\t|\n|\r| )*([0-9]|\(|\)|\*|\/|([a-z])*)(\t|\n|\r| )*")
```

The regex engine will try the other matches first, and if it finds a match, stop there. Only if none of the others match, does it try `([a-z])*` and since `*` is 'greedy', it will match all of `three`, then proceed to match `(` and finally `)`.

Read an explanation of how the full expression is tested [in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#index-13) (thanks to @kaya3).

However, if you put that sequence a the start, like here:

```py
patterns = (r"^(\t|\n|\r| )*(([a-z])*|[0-9]|\(|\)|\*|\/)(\t|\n|\r| )*")
```

It will now try to match it first. It's still greedy, so `three` still gets matched. But then on the next try, it will try to match `([a-z])*` to the remaining `'()'` - and it *matches*, since that string starts with zero letters.

It keeps matching it like that, and gets stuck in the loop. You can fix it by changing the `*` for a `+` which will only match if there is 1 or more matches:

```py
patterns = (r"^(\t|\n|\r| )*(([a-z])+|[0-9]|\(|\)|\*|\/)(\t|\n|\r| )*")
```

Comment: It's the beard, isn't it...? Sigh. You're welcome though. Feel free to accept the answer by clicking the checkmark instead of a kiss, so that the question appears as answered and can help others.

Comment: Suggested docs citation: *"As the target string is scanned, REs separated by '|' are tried from left to right."* ([link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#index-13)) - just to directly answer why the order matters.